# Cron job set to send mail is sending blank emails

Tags: php, email, cron

I'm using this simple script to detect website content change and mail if there is a change.I've set a cron job to run the script everyday and it's working fine but when script detects a change it sends blank email without body.Why thi is happening?Am I doing something wrong here(in the mail part)?

```
<?php

$contents = file_get_contents('http://izoneknr.com');
$hash     = file_get_contents('../heimdall/heimdall.txt'); 

if ($hash == ($pageHash = md5($contents))) 
{
 echo " the content is the same";
} 
else 
{

 $from = "Heimdall";
 $EmailTo = "smckannur@gmail.com,sourab.cc@gmail.com"; // Your email address here
 $Subject = "WEBSITE MODIFICATION ALERT";

 $headers.= "MIME-version: 1.0\n";
 $headers.= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
 $headers.= "From: $from\n";

 $message = '<html><body>';
 $message.= '<p>This is an automated response from mysite.The bridge is open.</p><br>';
 $message.= '<p>m7mysite has been updated.</p>';
 $message = '</body></html>';

 $success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $message,$headers);

 // store the new hash in the file
 $fp = fopen('../heimdall/heimdall.txt', 'w');
 fwrite($fp, $pageHash);
 fclose($fp);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overwriting the previously-assigned content with:

```
$message = '</body></html>';
```

Change it to:

```
$message .= '</body></html>';
```